# Is application enough secured against CSRF-attacks if I send AJAX requests with jQuery and only validate them X-Requested-With?

Tags: ajax, csrf

According to [this article](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2010/11/preventing-csrf-attacks-with-ajax-and-http-headers/) it is enough to validate X-Requested-With header for AJAX requests sent by jQuery. So in this case it is not necessary to implement tokens?

And if yes, where is defined that cross-browser requests are not allowed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The article itself says that this method is insufficient:

> Warning
>
> The method of preventing CSRF attacks described in this post
> is now considered to be insufficient. A comment on this post links to
> more details about an attack that circumvents it.

Comment: thanks for your remark. actually as i read this article there was no mention of this vulnerability.